# Button function not working like another one?

Tags: javascript, html, counting

So I'm trying to write this simple program which one will count the visitors who went into gallery. The problem is the function live their own life. I can see this one( I' m talking about: "Previous Entries:" ) start counting when the gallery is full but only to one. I tryed many ways. I think sometimes wrong is with function call

```js
let count = 0
let entryEl = document.getElementById("entry-el")
let leftEl = document.getElementById("left-el")
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
let previousEl = document.getElementById("previous-el")

function peopleInShop() {
  count += 1
  countEl.textContent = count
  if (count <= 5) {
    window.alert("Welcome")
  }
  if (count >= 6 && count != 0) {
    window.alert("You can not Entry to the shop now! Wait till someone left the shop!")
  }
  if (count == 6) {
    count -= 1
    countEl.textContent = 5
  } else {
    pass
  }

}

function left() {
  count -= 1
  if (count == -1) {
    count += 1
  }
  countEl.textContent = count

}

function previousVisitors() {
  a = 0
  a = a + 1
  previousEl.textContent = a
}
```

```html
<h1> People in the gallery:</h1>
<h2 id="count-el"> 0</h2>
<button id="entry-el" onclick="peopleInShop() ; previousVisitors()">Entry</button>
<button id="left-el" onclick="left()">Left</button>
<p> Previous Entries: </p>
<h3 id="previous-el">0</h3>
<br>
<p><u>Ther avarage quantity of people in the shop can not be higher than five persons!</u></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is set to 0 every time you call `previousVisitors()`. You need to declare the variable outside of the function like the others.

```js
let count = 0;
let entryEl = document.getElementById("entry-el");
let leftEl = document.getElementById("left-el");
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");
let previousEl = document.getElementById("previous-el");
let a = 0;

function peopleInShop() {
  //count += 1
  count++;
  countEl.textContent = count;
  if (count <= 5) {
    window.alert("Welcome");
  }
  if (count >= 6 && count !== 0) {
    window.alert("You can not Entry to the shop now! Wait till someone left the shop!");
  }
  if (count === 6) {
    //count -= 1;
    count--;
    countEl.textContent = 5;
  } else {
    //pass
  }

}

function left() {
  count--;
  if (count === -1) {
    count++;
  }
  countEl.textContent = count;

}

function previousVisitors() {
  a++;
  previousEl.textContent = a;
}
```

```html
<h1> People in the gallery:</h1>
<h2 id="count-el"> 0</h2>
<button id="entry-el" onclick="peopleInShop() ; previousVisitors()">Entry</button>
<button id="left-el" onclick="left()">Left</button>
<p> Previous Entries: </p>
<h3 id="previous-el">0</h3>
<br>
<p><u>Ther avarage quantity of people in the shop can not be higher than five persons!</u></p>
```

Also, `pass` is declared in Python but not JS. You can just leave those brackets empty. Also, in JS (and many other languages), `+= 1` and `-= 1` can be shortened to `++` and `--` respectively. And if you know that two variables will always be of the same type, then you can use `===` instead of `==` (JS only). `===` is faster since `==` converts data types in JS. Also, please end every line with a semicolon. It is not required in JS, but it is a standard, unlike Python.

Answer (score 0):

***Hi***,

First you have `pass` in your code that is undefined

So `js` code stop on the line `22`

If you haven't any to statement on fault just remove `else` statement

In `previousVisitors` function you have declare `a` variable in the function

So `a` always = 0

And you use `a = a + 1`

So previousVistors will always be `1`

To Solve declare `a` variable in `global scoop` not in `function`

like this

```
let a = 0;
function previousVisitors() {
  a = a + 1;
  previousEl.textContent = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = 0    
function previousVisitors() {
  a +=1
  previousEl.textContent = a
}
```

In your last function: Define **"a"** variable, And update the value when calling this function (When pressing the Button),

Call the function like That:

```
<button id="left-el" onclick="left();previousVisitors()">Left</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use js `addEventListener` to listen events of your moves (also `querySelector` is much better, because you can easily change **selectors**):

```
document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener("click", callback);
```

Add [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lalande-9vitp?file=/index.html) to the source code

```js
let count = 0;
let prevEntries = 0;

function counter(number) {
  if (count + number >= 0 && count + number <= 5 && prevEntries === 0) {
    count += number;
    document.querySelector("#count-el").innerHTML = count;
  } else {
    if (prevEntries + number >= 0 && count <= 5) {
      prevEntries += number;
    }

    document.querySelector("#previous-el").innerHTML = prevEntries;
  }
}

function addClickListener(selector, callback) {
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener("click", callback);
}

addClickListener("#entry-el", () => {
  counter(1);
});
addClickListener("#left-el", () => {
  counter(-1);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>People in the gallery:</h1>
    <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
    <button id="entry-el">
      Entry
    </button>
    <button id="left-el">Left</button>
    <p>Previous Entries:</p>
    <h3 id="previous-el">0</h3>
    <br />
    <p>
      <u
        >Ther avarage quantity of people in the shop can not be higher than five
        persons!</u
      >
    </p>

    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```